# How do I read individual PowerCfg settings?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, powercfg

If I run this command:

```
powercfg -SETACTIVE 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c
```

...I can subsequently run this command:

```
powercfg -GETACTIVESCHEME
```

...and it will tell me what I did. (It will output 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c.)

Similarly, if I run this command:

```
powercfg -change -monitor-timeout-dc 0
```

I want to know how I can query that. Is there some powercfg flag where I can read the current value of `monitor-timeout-dc`, and other settings like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This returns the monitor timeout (in seconds) to turn off. Note that i'm skiping 16 lines for DC timeout, if you want AC timeout then skip 15 lines.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set SCHEME=8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c
set VIDEO_GUID=7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99

for /f "skip=16 tokens=1*" %%a in ('powercfg -Q !SCHEME! !VIDEO_GUID!') do (
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%c in ('echo/%%a%%b') do (
set /a "timeout=%%c"&goto break))
:break
echo/%timeout%
pause>nul
```

You can query any configuration. For a list of schemes use `powercfg -list`, for a list of guids use `powercfg -aliases`

Comment: Important note is that seconds are displayed in HEX values, not decimal. A value of 100 = 256 seconds.

Comment: @JasonFaulkner You're right, but `set /a` converts the HEX value to Decimal value.

Comment: Nice. I did not know it did this automatically.

Comment: This is perfect. This is just what I needed. I've accepted your answer as correct, and I tried to give you the bounty right away as well; however SO says I need to wait a day before awarding it.