# How do I pull the time until sleep of the active power plan?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, sleep

I'm looking for either a PowerShell script or command that allows me to get the active power plan's time until sleep.

In the below example, I know from the previous screen that "Balanced" is the Active Power plan. Selecting that, gets to this screen where I can see this info.

[image: Sleep settings]

I've currently tried places in both WMI and the registry, but everything is set to GUIDs and you have to pull the Active Powerplan first. I have also tried `powercfg` and it various commands.

Do I have to query the active powerplan with powercfg, parse that response, so I only get the GUID, and then query using that result in the registry or WMI?

Looking for some guidance or even some code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to READ the auto sleep time of pc from powercfg.exe (batch)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39606633/how-to-read-the-auto-sleep-time-of-pc-from-powercfg-exe-batch)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read individual PowerCfg settings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049663/how-do-i-read-individual-powercfg-settings)

Answer (score 0):

Use powershell command to find out current and active Power plan.

```
gwmi -Namespace Root\CIMV2\power -Class win32_powerplan  -Filter isActive=’true’ | select ElementName , Description, InstanceID
```

and then use `instanceID` to query **powercfg**

```
powercfg /QUERY <InstanceID>
```